# Rubocop line length too long, how do I shorten given line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2, rubocop

Rubocop is telling me my line length is too long.  How do I fix the formatting on a line like these without my code breaking? What are the rules that allow you to use the next line?

```
  belongs_to :car, -> { includes(:listable).where(listings: {listable_type: Car.to_s}) }, foreign_key: :listable_id
```

and

```
  raise ArgumentError, "Can only initiate inherited Classes of Base, not Base Directly" if self.class == Registration::Base
```

Comment: You can always [change the maximum line length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37228672/3784008) in your configuration. I always set it to 120 or higher. 80 characters is absurd.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of places where it is legal to insert newlines in Ruby. For example your first snippet:

```
belongs_to(
  :car,
  -> {
    includes(
      :listable
    )
    .where(
      listings:
        {
          listable_type:
            Car
            .to_s
        }
    )
  },
  foreign_key:
    :listable_id
)
```

Your second snippet simply doesn't make sense. An object *always* knows its own class, there is *never ever* a reason for an object to check its own class. That is not just a code smell or an anti-pattern, that is a *huge red flag* that the author of that code has no understanding of object-orientation and inheritance.

The second snippet should be refactored using the [*Replace Conditional with Polymorphism Refactoring*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30924800/2988). You don't show enough code to see exactly how, but I would suggest something like this:

```
class Registration::Base
  def initialize
    raise ArgumentError, 'Can only initiate inherited Classes of Base, not Base Directly' 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would write it:

```
belongs_to :car,
  -> { includes(:listable).where(listings: {listable_type: Car.to_s}) },
  foreign_key: :listable_id
```

and

```
if self.class == Registration::Base
  raise ArgumentError, 'Can only initiate inherited Classes of Base, not Base Directly'
end
```

Note that the `rubocop` rule for "You should inline `if` statements" does not apply when doing so would make the line too long.