# Rubocop, how to Disable/Enable cops on blocks of code

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I will like to disable a cop for a specific block or method.

I know it is possible to disable a cop for the whole project using `.rubocop.yml`, but I just want to deactivate the cop temporarily for a specific portion of the code.

Comment: https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html#disabling-cops-within-source-code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37228672/5025116

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuboCop: Line is too long ← How to Ignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228624/rubocop-line-is-too-long-%e2%86%90-how-to-ignore)

Comment: I created the question/answer because I was never finding it in the google results. Hoping adding it here it will give it more visibility

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I answer my question because it is always very difficult for me to find the reference to this solution:

```
# rubocop:disable Metrics/MethodLength
def my_code
  ..
end
# rubocop:enable Metrics/MethodLength
```

Same for multiple cops:

```
# rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize, Metrics/MethodLength
def my_code
  ..
end
# rubocop:enable Metrics/AbcSize, Metrics/MethodLength
```

Documentation: https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html#disabling-cops-within-source-code

Answer (score 19):

If you want to disable the cop for a particular line, you can just use something like this

```
 before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show] # rubocop:disable Style/SymbolArray
```

No need to enable it again. If there is a block of code and you want to enable or disable the cop, then as suggested above, you can follow that approach.