# Rubocop finds an offense on a migration change method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

On my migration file I have a number of new fields creation.

```
create_table :mytable do |t|
  t.string :my_field, null: false
  .........
```

And I am getting the following

```
 Metrics/AbcSize: Assignment Branch Condition size for change is too high. [<1, 17, 0> 17.03/17]
```

What is the proper way to avoid that?

Comment: ignore migration files in rubocop.yml

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36896588/4758119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common practice to [exclude](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/1.37/configuration.html#includingexcluding-files) the `db` folder in your `.rubocop.yml`.

```yaml
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - 'db/**/*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time we Ignore **./db** folder in rubocp.yml file. Other than that we can disable cops for a specific block of code. Here is the answer **[Rubocop, how to Disable/Enable cops on blocks of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67425427/rubocop-how-to-disable-enable-cops-on-blocks-of-code)**